# I need to be able to change the title of the frame in java via a button in another class

Tags: java, swing, frames

I've been looking online for about 2 hours now. What I need to complete is a way to have a button in another class, change the title of the frame window for the whole program. So basically I want to make it so the customer can change the setTitle to whatever his business name is. Here is the code I have so far for both classes that will be involved in this issue.

Options.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Options extends JPanel {
    JLabel nameLabel;
    JTextField nameField;
    JButton sNn;

    public Options()
    {
        nameLabel = new JLabel();
        nameLabel.setText("Change Company Name:");
        nameField = new JTextField(22);
        sNn = getTitleChangeButton();
        ExitButton exitButton = new ExitButton();

        this.add(nameLabel);
        this.add(nameField);
        this.add(sNn);
        this.add(exitButton.getExitButton());   
    }

    public JButton getTitleChangeButton()
    {
        JButton ChangeTitle; 
        ChangeTitle = new JButton("Change Company Title");
        ChangeTitle.setMnemonic('C');
        ChangeTitle.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {       
                String title;       
            }
        });
            return ChangeTitle;
            }
        }
```

here is the second class called tabbedPane. This is the class that I want to be the superclass and have the setTitle changed via the button.

TabbedPane.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
//import poolCalculation.PoolVolumeCalc;
//import poolCalculation.GenTab;
//import poolCalculation.TempCalc;
import poolCalculation.Options;

public class TabbedPane extends JFrame
{
    public TabbedPane()
    {

        setTitle("Gardening INC.");

        JTabbedPane Tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        getContentPane().add(Tabs);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();

        //Tabs.addTab("Pool Volume Calculator", new PoolVolumeCalc());
        //Tabs.addTab("General Tab", new GenTab());
        //Tabs.addTab("Temperature Calculation", new TempCalc());
        Tabs.addTab("Options", new Options());

        getContentPane().add(Tabs);
        setSize(400,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TabbedPane test = new TabbedPane();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the title to change for the frame when the user clicks the button in options. Here is what I have tried so far, I have tried making setTitle(title) and making that a string in the main section of TabbedPane and then using a get method to get the text from options, but that didn't work. Or I did it wrong. I tried making the button its own class, but ran into not being able to read the textfield.

Comment: Can you include a reference to the JFrame whose title you want to change as a field of the options class, then call `jFReference.setTitle(newTitle)`?

Comment: your probably right and that would of been the easier way....bonks head.  I did however get an answer from the poster below.  That seemed to work with a little more code.  Either way im happy with the output i got.  Thanks for responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that demonstrates how to change the title dynamically:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NormalFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NormalFrame()
    {
        super("The title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new CustomPanel(this));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new NormalFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel lbl;
    private JTextField txt;
    private JButton btn;

    private ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            mainFrame.setTitle(txt.getText());
        }
    };

    public CustomPanel(JFrame mainFrame)
    {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;

        lbl = new JLabel("The new title: ");
        txt = new JTextField(10);
        btn = new JButton("Change Title");
        btn.addActionListener(listener);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(lbl, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(txt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btn, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though, it might can work, but I doubt, it's really a good practise to use `this` inside the constructor :( as you doing inside your `NormalFrame` Class, though +1 for the SSCCE :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked out great.  I did a few changes, because i dont really like how borderlayout works.  But the actual beef of the code that i was doing wrong was a great help.  Thanks so much

Comment: @user1460026 You are welcome, I am glad that I could help :) .. BTW, don't forget to accept this answer as the right answer.

Comment: Im assuming its the green check mark...but im not sure never used this site before XD

Comment: @popas yes, it is. Welcome to Stackoverflow ;)